# Error with OnClickListener on menu item for animation

Tags: java, android

I want to set an `OnClickListener` to an Item from my Menu but the ImageView item isn't found. I need this `OnCLickListener` for my refresh animation on the reload button.

```js
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_training, menu);

        // Declare ImageView and Animation for rotation animation
        ImageView reloadButton = (ImageView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_reloadbutton).getActionView();

        // Set onClick listener for button press action
        reloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Liste aktualisieren gedrückt!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_reloadbutton"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_reloadentry"
        android:title="@string/menu_reloadentry"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

This is the error:

> `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Anyhow, the right way of handling a menu item click would be overriding the `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

Comment: Dear Blackbelt, I took a look at you "exact duplicate qestion" flag and I can't found any part who is same as my question.

Comment: @JuanMartinez And how can I do this? I need to get the reload button item for setting an animation on it

Comment: @JuanMartinez I need it in the next our.. I have big stress at the moment so I would be very apreciate if you can help me :(

Comment: Here's a simple example, take a look at how `onOptionsItemSelected` is used and I'm sure you'll figure it out: [http://www.javatpoint.com/android-option-menu-example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-option-menu-example). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Put this in your activity:
    `@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_reloadbutton:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Liste aktualisieren gedrückt!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }`